# Closed connections remain idle in postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, tomcat, connection-pooling

Problem: closed connections created as follows remain `idle` in the `postgres` database.

```
public class MyConnectionHandler() implements AutoCloseable {
    private Connection connection;
    private CopyManager copymanager;

    public void init() {
        //need the following in order to work with postgres COPY api
        connection = ((PooledConnection) dataSource.getConnection()).getConnection();
        copymanager = ((Jdbc4Connection) connection).getCopyAPI();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

I'm using tomcat pooling provided by `tomcat-jdbc` in context of `spring-boot`. But that should not matter for my problem:

When I create the connection, and close it afterwards, the connection is still idle in my database. `select * from pg_stat_activity` there I can still see the connections, although they where closed explicit.

This means, if I create like 10 connections over the day, and close them after some time, the connections will grow continuously. They are never removed from the db.

What could be the problem? Why do they remain in state `idle` even if they are closed?
Only when I shutdown my java program the connections are removed (of course).

I also tried setting the following spring properties without any impact on idle connections:

```
spring.datasource.initial-size=1
spring.datasource.max-idle=1
spring.datasource.min-idle=1
```

Comment: "*But that should not matter for my problem*" - actually it **does** matter. because you get the connections from the pool, the `close()` method only puts them "back" into the pool. One of the purposes of a connection pool is to not permanently open and close _physical_ connections. You need to configure your connection pool to e.g. close them after a certain idle time. You need to read the manual for the connection pool you are using (DBCA, Tomcat7 Pool, ...)

Comment: Yes you're right, but if I initialize liek 200 connections and close them directly, they all will remain idle in the db. spring also offers properties to take control over the connection-pool. I tried with the properties in my update above to restrict to a single connection, anyways after close any created connections are still idle...

Comment: Again: that's how a connection pool works. You need to show us the configuration of the pool. So far everything is working as expected.

Comment: The pooling class is `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` with spring configuring the pool as stated in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html under # DATASOURCE.

Comment: Thanks for your hints on the connection pool. With that help, I could identify the root cause: I was checking `datasource.getConnection() instanceof ...`, but that lead to the unclosed connections. Of course it is better to perform the instancecheck after saving the connection object in the member variable, that is closed lateron...

Comment: Why on earth do you need to do an `instanceof` check?

Comment: Because the class will be part of an internal framework that might use different connection pooling libraries. But getting the `COPY` api is different for each connection pool unfortunately, thus the instancecheck. One more sidequestion: do you think the connection should be closed explicit at all in a connection pool? Probably I should remove that too?